# WPF: Image control of a CroppedBitmap as BitmapImage is still uncropped Image (Conversion Problem?)

Tags: c#, wpf, type-conversion, crop, bitmapimage

I am trying to Crop a `BitmapImage` in my WPF application `StageWindow.Stage` using the `CroppedBitmap` class.

When saving the new cropped image to file `JpegBitmapEncoder` I can see the correctly  cropped image. `CroppedBitmap Crop`

However I actually want to save the cropped image into a `List\<BitmapImage\>` for later use in another WPF image control. That list contains `BitmapImages` already so changing it to `CroppedBitmaps` would not suffice.

to be able to store the new croppedBitmap I use something like this:

```
    BitmapImage xx = CroppedBitmap1 as BitmapImage;
```

when setting an WPF image control to the `new BitmapImage` (**ExpectedCroppedImage**) it still displays the `CroppedBitmaps` original source image without the crop.

I suspect the code above to delete the crop attribute from the new `BitmapImage` because the `BitmapImage` itself has no attributes for the cropped Area. But how can I save only the cropped part into a new `BitmapImage`?

I have been searching around but it seems CroppedBitmap should do the trick I just dont know how to convert it back in the correct manner.

Here is the Code for clarification:

```
    //Stage is the WPF image element that im reading the source image from.
    
    ImageSource StageWindowImageSource = StageWindow.Stage.Source;
    CroppedBitmap Crop = new CroppedBitmap((BitmapSource)StageWindowImageSource, new Int32Rect(0,0,50,50));
        
    ExpectedCroppedImage = Crop.Source as BitmapImage;
                            
    JpegBitmapEncoder jpg = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    jpg.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(Crop));
    FileStream fp = new FileStream("F:/Crop.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    jpg.Save(fp);
    fp.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
ExpectedCroppedImage = Crop.Source as BitmapImage;
```

does not return the cropped bitmap, but the original one from which the crop was taken, i.e. the `Source` bitmap.

Besides that, you don't need any conversion from `CroppedBitmap` to `BitmapImage`.

Instead, use a base class of BitmapImage and CroppedBitmap as element type of the List, i.e. use a `List<BitmapSource>` or `List<ImageSource>` for your collection.

Now you can assign instances of any class derived from the element type.

```
List<BitmapSource> images = ...

CroppedBitmap croppedImage = new CroppedBitmap(...); 
images.Add(croppedImage);

BitmapImage someOtherImage = new BitmapImage(...); 
images.Add(someOtherImage);
```

Comment: while this is not giving me the desired BitmapImage it still is the easaiest solution for my project so im marking this as correct answer. Im still thinking how it is possible that the croppedBitmap source is still "more than actually needed". Isnt this a bit  of a waste of memory? I guess it would be neglectible...

Comment: The easiest way to crop a bitmap in WPF is to use a CroppedBitmap. And for the *desired* BitmapImage, you don't actually need that. You can assign any other ImageSource to the Source property of an Image element.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    ImageSource   StageWindowImageSource = img.Source;
    CroppedBitmap Crop                   = new CroppedBitmap((BitmapSource) StageWindowImageSource, new Int32Rect(20, 20, 150, 110));

    img2.Source = GetImage(Crop, new JpegBitmapEncoder());
}

private BitmapImage GetImage(BitmapSource source, BitmapEncoder encoder)
{
    var image = new BitmapImage();

    using (var sourceMs = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
        encoder.Save(sourceMs);

        sourceMs.Position = 0;
        using (var destMs = new MemoryStream(sourceMs.ToArray()))
        {
            image.BeginInit();
            image.StreamSource = destMs;
            image.CacheOption  = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.EndInit();
            image.Freeze();
        }
    }

    return image;
}
```

Comment: This conversion is entirely redundant. `img2.Source = Crop;` would work as well.